# the classic algorithm to find orientation of three points is wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

The algorithm could be referred here (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/91primitives/) and here (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/orientation-3-ordered-points/),

Try below code for p1 = {0, 0}, p2 = {4, 4}, p3 = {0, 3}, or p1 = {0, 0}, p2 = {4, 4}, p3 = {0, 5}, I think both cases should be clock wise, but the algorithm output counter clock wise.

```
// A C++ program to find orientation of three points
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};

// To find orientation of ordered triplet (p1, p2, p3).
// The function returns following values
// 0 --> p, q and r are colinear
// 1 --> Clockwise
// 2 --> Counterclockwise
int orientation(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
{
    // See 10th slides from following link for derivation
    // of the formula
    int val = (p2.y - p1.y) * (p3.x - p2.x) -
            (p2.x - p1.x) * (p3.y - p2.y);

    cout << val << endl;
    if (val == 0) return 0; // colinear

    return (val > 0)? 1: 2; // clock or counterclock wise
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    Point p1 = {0, 0}, p2 = {4, 4}, p3 = {0, 3};
    int o = orientation(p1, p2, p3);
    if (o==0)        cout << "Linear";
    else if (o == 1) cout << "Clockwise";
    else             cout << "CounterClockwise";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (0,0) -> (4, 4) -> (0, 3) sounds like counter clockwise to me.

Comment: Yes, @serhiyb, you can try my code, it outputs counter clock wise.

Comment: Which is the correct answer. So what is your question then?

Comment: @serhiyb,  my question is it seems the algorithm or code is wrong for the example we just discussed? Or the code is not implemented correctly in some case? If you have any thoughts, it will be great.

Comment: (0,0) -> (4,4) -> (0, 3) is counter clockwise. Algorithm outputs counter clockwise. Perfect match! Same for your second example.

Comment: @serhiyb, sorry I mis-read your comments before. Why you think it is counter clock wise? I think it is clock wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's draw the sequence `(0, 0) -> (4, 4) -> (0, 3)`:

[image]

As you can see, it is counter-clockwise. Thus the code works correctly, and you simply made an error in judgement.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have some wrong understanding what means counter clock wise in this context, with your sample diagram, I have got the idea, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clockwise or counterclockwise depends on your axis orientation !

What really matters is that the triangle test gives 0 for aligned points, positive on one side and negative on the other.

Just take one test case and you will know forever what is the right "signedness".